# How can I delete the directory with the highest number name?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory containing sub-directories, some of whose names are numbers.  Without looking, I don't know what the numbers are.  How can I delete the sub-directory with the highest number name?  I reckon the solution might sort the sub-directories into reverse order and select the first sub-directory that begins with a number but I don't know how to do that.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 cd $yourdir             #go to that dir
 ls -q -p     |             #list all files directly in dir and make directories end with /
 grep '^[0-9]*/$' |      #select directories (end with /) whose names are made of numbers
 sort -n |               #sort numerically
 tail -n1 |              #select the last one (largest)
 xargs -r rmdir          #or rm -r if nonempty
```

Recommend running it first without the `xargs -r rmdir` or `xargs -r rm -r` part to make sure your deleting the right thing.

Comment: I'd +1 you but don't parse `ls`: `printf "%s\n" */ | grep -v '[^0-9/]' | sort ...`

Comment: @PSkocik `mkdir $'a\n10000'`. Surprise.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf All the more reason to prefer `ls`. My version actually WORKS with that (GNU ls replaces newlines in filenames with question marks). If I do `printf "%s\n"`, I end up trying to remove 10000—a possibly nonexistent directory.

Comment: @PSkocik: no, output of `ls` doesn't replace newlines with question marks in pipes, unless you use `-q`. This is stated in the documentation: _show non graphic characters as-is  (default  unless  program  is 'ls' and output is a terminal)_ under the option `--show-control-chars`.

Answer (score 1):

A pure Bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob extglob

# Make an array of all the dir names that only contain digits
dirs=( +([[:digit:]])/ )

# If none found, exit
if ((${#dirs[@]}==0)); then
    echo >&2 "No dirs found"
    exit
fi

# Loop through all elements of array dirs, saving the greatest number
max=${dirs[0]%/}
for i in "${dirs[@]%/}"; do
    ((10#$max<10#$i)) && max=$i
done

# Finally, delete the dir with largest number found
echo rm -r "$max"
```

Note:

- This will have an unpredictable behavior when there are dirs with same number but written differently, e.g., `2` and `0002`.
- Will fail if the numbers overflow Bash's numbers.
- Doesn't take into account negative numbers and non-integer numbers.
- Remove the `echo` in the last line if you're happy with it.
- To be run from within your directory.

Comment: I'd upvote it for its being pure-bash, but alas, it fails for me at step two (finds only one subdirectory in a directory with multiple matches).

Comment: @PSkocik are you sure you copied the whole script? can you please provide a tree example where the script fails?

Comment: My bad. Made an error. Tried to do echo $dir after the second line and forgot I need that special "${dirs[@]}" for echoing arrays. :). My upvote belongs to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's make some directories to test the script:

```
mkdir test; cd test; mkdir $(seq 100)
```

Now

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | cut -c 3- | sort -k1n | tail -n 1 | xargs -r echo rm -r
```

Result:

```
rm -r 100
```

Now, remove the word `echo` from the command and `xargs` will execute `rm -r 100`.

Comment: Won't work if, e.g., there are only two directories named `a` and `0`: OP specified that _some_ of the sub-directory names are numbers; not all of them.

Comment: Right, `find` is missing parameters `-regex "./[0-9]+"`.