# My directory names contain a number. How can I find the largest number?

Tags: bash, variables, grep, gnuplot

Within a directory, I have sub-directories, whose names are foo$i (where $i is an integer).  How can I find the largest value of $i?  Thank you.

My question was marked down for "not showing any research effort, being unclear or not useful" but that's not true.  Previously, I had asked this question [How can I delete the directory with the highest number name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26283761/how-can-i-delete-the-directory-with-the-highest-number-name) but, though I could use the solution, I didn't understand it well enough to be able to modify it.  I have read somewhere in Stack Overflow that answers are not meant to be tutorials.  I appreciate that.  That being said, it is not always easy to figure out how to modify somebody else's solution to solve your own problem.  I also thought that, rather than go through what I had tried, because it would be long-winded, I thought I would just ask a simple, clear question.

The thing is, I don't understand the answers I've been given to this question and now I have another, related question.  I will try to explain it clearly and hope that I'm not marked down again!

Within a directory, I have sub-directories, whose names are integers.  How can I find the largest value integer, assign it a value and use it in a GNUplot script?

So far, I can find the integer value by using the code from the solution to my previous question:

```
ls -pq | grep '^[0-9]*/$' | sort -n | tail -n1
```

Perhaps this code is too elaborate for my new problem but it works.

Let's say this integer has value $INT.

Now I want to assign this value to a line of GNUplot code:

```
path="path/to/directory/$INT/file_name"
```

Please can you tell me how to assign the value of my largest directory to a variable and pass it to the GNUplot script?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ls -al
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 myname myname 4096 Oct 13 08:25 .
drwxrwxrwt 14 root   root   4096 Oct 13 08:25 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 myname myname 4096 Oct 13 08:25 foo1
drwxr-xr-x  2 myname myname 4096 Oct 13 08:25 foo12
drwxr-xr-x  2 myname myname 4096 Oct 13 08:25 foo2
$ find . -name "a*" -type d| sed 's/.*foo//g'| sort -n | tail -n1
12
```

If above isn't OK to you, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-v` option for `ls` to sort the directories by "version strings". The last file shown is the one with the highest number.

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -v foo+([0-9])
```

It's not recommended to parse the output of `ls` in a script, though. If your dir names are more complicated, it can break. You can just accumulate the max in a loop:

```
max=0
shopt -s extglob
for f in foo+([0-9]) ; do
    n=${f#foo};
    if (( n > max )) ; then
        max=$n
   fi
done
echo "foo$max"
```

Whatever you do, be careful. In the moment you report the highest number, there can already be another subdir with a higher number!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a directory: `Test/` and some subdirectories with an index (e.g. run number):

```
Run1
Run2
Run3
Run7
Run07
Run007
```

and in each subdirectory the identical filename, e.g. `Data.dat`, but not necessarily identical content:

```
1  2.0
2  5.0
3  3.0
```

The following script will extract the indices and return the maximum. In this specially constructed example, the maximum is `7`. So, depending on the string creation for the variable `myLatestFile` via `sprintf()` you can decide whether you want to have the file, e.g. from directory `7` (`%d`) or `007` (`%03d`) being plotted.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.0 under Windows and maybe with earlier versions under Linux)

```
### plot a file from the subdirectory with the largest index
reset

DIR  = 'Test/'
FILE = "Data.dat"

SUBDIRS = system(sprintf('dir /b "%s"',DIR))   # Windows, gnuplot>=5.0.0
# SUBDIRS = system(sprintf('ls %s',DIR))       # Linux/MacOS

mySubDirPrefix  = "Run"
getIdx(s)       = int(substr(s,strlen(mySubDirPrefix)+1,strlen(s)))
maxIdx          = 0
do for [SUBDIR in SUBDIRS] {
    idx = getIdx(SUBDIR)
    maxIdx = idx>maxIdx ? maxIdx=idx : maxIdx
}

myLatestFile = sprintf("%s%s%d/%s",DIR,mySubDirPrefix,maxIdx,FILE)

plot myLatestFile u 1:2 w lp pt 7 ti sprintf("Highest directory index: %d",maxIdx)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Workaround for gnuplot>=4.6.0 and <5.0.0 under Windows:**

The use of `system()` as a function, i.e. `FILES = system("dir /b")` doesn't work with gnuplot>=4.x under Windows.
You will get a warning:

```
warning: system evaluation not supported by MS-Windows 32 bit
```

and the variable `SUBDIRS` will be an empty string.

As a retro-workaround you can use a temporary file:

```
# workaround for gnuplot>=4.6
TEMP = "dirs.txt"
system sprintf(sprintf('dir /b "%s" > %s',DIR,TEMP))
SUBDIRS = ''
stats TEMP u (SUBDIRS = SUBDIRS.' '.strcol(1)) nooutput  # append all subdirs into a string
```